# importError: no module named myapp in pyramid application

Tags: python-2.7, pyramid, pylons, pyramid-debug-toolbar

i am a newbie in python.

I have created an application using pyramid framewok but i am getting an error which is

`ImportError: No module named myapp`

My stack Trace is as follows

`2014-11-28 19:22:44,561 ERROR [pyramid_debugtoolbar][Dummy-1] Exception at http://127.0.0.1:9999/
traceback url: http://127.0.0.1:9999/_debug_toolbar/exception?token=a64896d3bad076fe2980&tb=140525154036112
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.2.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 177, in toolbar_tween
    response = _handler(request)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.2.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/performance.py", line 57, in resource_timer_handler
    result = handler(request)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.8-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 92, in tm_tween
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.8-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 73, in tm_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 163, in handle_request
    response = view_callable(context, request)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 377, in rendered_view
    context)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 418, in render_view
    return self.render_to_response(response, system, request=request)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 441, in render_to_response
    result = self.render(value, system_values, request=request)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 421, in render
    renderer = self.renderer
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/decorator.py", line 37, in __get__
    val = self.wrapped(inst)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 405, in renderer
    return factory(self)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_chameleon-0.3-py2.7.egg/pyramid_chameleon/zpt.py", line 10, in renderer_factory
    return renderer.template_renderer_factory(info, ZPTTemplateRenderer)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_chameleon-0.3-py2.7.egg/pyramid_chameleon/renderer.py", line 140, in template_renderer_factory
    return lookup(info)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_chameleon-0.3-py2.7.egg/pyramid_chameleon/renderer.py", line 115, in __call__
    filename)
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 949, in resource_filename
    return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename(
  File "/home/techencephalon/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 229, in get_provider
    __import__(moduleOrReq)
ImportError: No module named myapp`

i have no idea about this error to get any idea to fix this.

I am using mongodb in this applicaiton.

Comment: What were your immediately prior steps (inputs/outputs)?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend newbies work through the [Quick Tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/index.html) in order to get a solid understanding of how to develop web applications in Python using Pyramid as the medium.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm years late but,

import in python using modules (pyramid uses) is a little bit tricky.

What I do is this:

for example, in `views.py`

```py
from .tablas import julio2019
#import .tablas #if you want
ancho   =12
alto    = 7
color   ='#0CA309'
html4   = julio2019(ancho,alto,color)
```

and `tablas.py` should be in the same directory as `views.py`

In your case, `myApp` maybe is not in the same directory or you omitted the dot. Note that, when using `julio2019` function, its not necessary to use add `tablas.julio2019(..)` but you can if you want to.